# Cross button on iPhone app icon doesn't appear when trying to uninstall

Tags: ios, applications

When I tap and hold on an app icon on my iPhone to uninstall it, the ⓧ button  do not appear for certain apps. As far as I recall, the apps in question were installed using a different Apple ID which I have since removed from my iPhone.

I also tried uninstalling by going to Settings app → General → iPhone Storage → *App Name*, but couldn't find the Delete App option even there.

This is a company owned iPhone 5s running iOS 12.3.1. The device remotely managed. The apps in question are not managed and were installed using a personal ID.

Comment: Uninstalling apps not installed with the current Apple ID should work the same. If the iPhone is company owned, is there some kind of device management in place, or policies which install certain apps by default?

Comment: yes . device management is there . that is only for company app . the apps in question are like 'tripadvisor' , etc .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) It should help with the answer if you can mention the model of iPhone and the version of iOS running on your iPhone.

Comment: iphone 5s ; iOS 12.3.1

Comment: 'Deleting Apps' option under Screen Time was 'Don't Allow' . As soon as we put it to 'Allow' , the apps delete is possible now .

Comment: Thanks Team , for showing your concern .

Comment: @SanjibKumarMaulik Please answer it and close it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Screen Time settings were preventing the app from being uninstalled from my iPhone. The setting can be found by going to Settings app → Screen Time → Content & Privacy Restrictions → iTunes & App Store Purchases → Deleting Apps. The setting was set to **Don't Allow**.

[image]

As soon as the setting was changed to **Allow** (default value), I was able to uninstall apps normally and the ⓧ button appeared on the app icons when I tap and hold my finger.

When uninstalling an iPhone app, it doesn't matter if it was installed using the currently logged in Apple ID or using an Apple ID that has since been removed from the iPhone.